# Can SQLAlchemy DateTime Objects Only Be Naive?

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy

I am working with SQLAlchemy, and I'm not yet sure which database I'll use under it, so I want to remain as DB-agnostic as possible.  How can I store a timezone-aware datetime object in the DB without tying myself to a specific database?  Right now, I'm making sure that times are UTC before I store them in the DB, and converting to localized at display-time, but that feels inelegant and brittle.  Is there a DB-agnostic way to get a timezone-aware datetime out of SQLAlchemy instead of getting naive datatime objects out of the DB?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is a `timezone` parameter to [`DateTime`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime) column time, so there is no problem with storing timezone-aware `datetime` objects. However I found convenient to convert stored `datetime` to UTC automatically with simple type decorator:

```
from sqlalchemy import types
from datetime import datetime, timezone

class UTCDateTime(types.TypeDecorator):

    impl = types.DateTime

    def process_bind_param(self, value, engine):
        if value is None:
            return
        if value.utcoffset() is None:
            raise ValueError(
                'Got naive datetime while timezone-aware is expected'
            )
        return value.astimezone(timezone.utc)

    def process_result_value(self, value, engine):
        if value is not None:
            return value.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Note, that is behaves nicely when you use naive `datetime` by accident (meaning it will raise a ValueError).

Comment: This doesn't work as written, it needs a minor tweak in `process_bind_param`: `def process_bind_param(self, value, engine):\n  if value is not None:\n      if value.tzinfo is None:\n        return value.replace(tzinfo=tzutc())\n      else:\n        return value.astimezone(tzutc())`

Comment: @Jesse Dhillon: it's intentional to prevent accidental storage of naive datetime objects, while your recipe incorrectly inteprets any datetime with any timezone as being UTC.

Comment: @Dennis, so using your type, one is expected to create and store only timezone-aware `datetime` objects? Now that I understand that, I like your solution more because it requires the user to be explicit about what they are saving.

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking that the last bit, where it creates the datetime, is equivalent to `value.replace(tzinfo=tzutc())` as seen here: http://mindlace.net/2012/11/13/make-datetime-naive-for-mysql-in-sqlalchemy/ ? Or does one do something slightly different? I'm scared of getting something wrong here!

Comment: @DenisOtkidach Very elegant solution.  Time to update some orm code to use UTCDateTime :)

Comment: @OrganicPanda Yes, it's possible to simplify it as you described. Both expressions evaluate to the same value. You can test it yourself by substituting `value` for any `datetime` object.

Comment: Wouldn't this conversion prevent using database index on date column when selecting based on date as in `q = query.filter(my_table.c.start_date >= some_date)`?

Comment: The SQLAlchemy docs has a recipe: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html#store-timezone-aware-timestamps-as-timezone-naive-utc

Comment: I'm having trouble using this recipe when combining with `from_statement`, created a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69181651/using-custom-type-with-sqlalchemy-why-are-the-results-of-process-result-value-n does anyone know of a workaround for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am addressing the desire to have datetime-aware in my code by using UTC in all internal instances. The only issue I came up with was when reading the database. Despite writing datetime-aware to the database, when retrieving the format is naive. My fix was:

```
import pytz

dt = mydb.query.filter_by(name='test').first().last_update.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

- `dt` is the variable that will store the last_update retrieved in datetime format
- `mydb` is the name of my db table
- `name` is one of the columns in the table
- `last_update` is a column that is stored in the format datetime

The trick is `replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)`

Answer (score 1):

The SQLAlchemy documentation has [a recipe for this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html#store-timezone-aware-timestamps-as-timezone-naive-utc):

```
import datetime

class TZDateTime(TypeDecorator):
    impl = DateTime

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            if not value.tzinfo:
                raise TypeError("tzinfo is required")
            value = value.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc).replace(
                tzinfo=None
            )
        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = value.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
        return value
```