# sqlalchemy query comparing function on multiple columns to another value

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Using sqlalchemy, how do i set up a filter that is comparing the value of one column to the value of a function run on multiple columns.

The goal is to write an orm query that selects objects where dt_added + max_age seconds < now.

If I were to just write the raw sql, this is the statement I'd be going for:

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable s
WHERE DATE_ADD(s.dt_added,interval max_age second) < NOW()
```

The solutions I looked at suggest using raw python datetime objects, but that won't work here because different rows have different values for max_age.  The math has to happen on the server side.

```
class SomeObject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sometable'
    some_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    modified = Column(DateTime, nullable=False,
        server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
    max_age = Column(Integer)
```

Sample data:

```
id, dt_added, max_age
 1, 2015-12-30 12:15:00, 3600
 2, 2015-12-30 12:15:00, 60
```

If the current datetime was '2015-12-30 12:20:00' it would return row 2, but not row 1.

I am able to force the issue using raw text, but I'd rather do it completely through the orm.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text

query = ses.query(
    SomeObject
).filter(
    func.date_add(
        SomeObject.created,
        text('INTERVAL max_age second')
    ) < datetime.datetime.now()
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Would you be able to use `unix time` instead of date time objects, or be able to convert said date time objects? That way you are only storing an integer and ages are easier to calculate: http://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: If you can use UTC time, I'd recommend taking a look at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2528453/1703772

Comment: UTC isn't an option here unfortunately.  The table def I gave is simplified, but in reality Its a tool to interface with a larger legacy application with hundreds of tables that is standardized on datetime fields.