# Date type for sqlachemy is passing timezone

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following:

```
class Atom(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'atom'

    id                = Column( Integer, primary_key=True)
    date              = Column( Date, nullable=False,  doc="date on which delivery occurred" )`
```

I look at the sql sent and I see the following for date
'date': `datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())`

so when I pass 2016-03-01 and look in db I see 2016-02-29

How can I stop sqlachemy from adding the tzinfo for a Date type?

Comment: If it's a date column, why do you have a `datetime`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be:

```
date = Column(DateTime(timezone=False),
              nullable=False,
              doc="date on which delivery occurred"
       )
```

According to the [SQLAlchemy Changelog](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/changelog_02.html?highlight=tzinfo) you can switch the time zone in this way:

> added “timezone=True” flag to DateTime and Time types. postgres so far
>   will convert this to “TIME[STAMP] (WITH|WITHOUT) TIME ZONE”, so that
>   control over timezone presence is more controllable (psycopg2 returns
>   datetimes with tzinfo’s if available, which can create confusion
>   against datetimes that don’t).

Another option is to set the specific timezone, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414952/sqlalchemy-datetime-timezone).